# How to export dependency include dir in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, header-files

I have 3 projects.

my.exe, pcl.lib and flann.lib.

my.exe uses pcl.lib and pcl.lib uses flann.lib.

In one of pcl.lib's header file, it includes flann.h, so for my.exe, it needs to `find_package` both `pcl` and `flann` to include the header files from both 2 libraries. This is not perfect because I don't want my.exe to know the existance of flann, at least in cmake find_package.

One solution is to use `INTERFACE` in pcl project for flann:

```
target_link_libraries(pcl INTERFACE flann)
```

But the problem is that pcl is a complicated project and `target_link_libraries(pcl ...` has been used elsewhere and I got this error in cmake:

> The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
> the target "pcl".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a
> target must be either all-keyword or all-plain.

`target_link_libraries(pcl`   has been used without INTERFACE, PUBLIC or PRIVATE keywords already so I can't use `target_link_libraries(pcl`   with `INTERFACE`.

So in this case, How can set the include directories as `INTERFACE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to introduce an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries) as intermediary target like this:

```
# both pcl and flann must be known at this point
add_library(pcl_if INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(pcl_if INTERFACE pcl flann)
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` where `my` is defined:

```
target_link_libraries(my PUBLIC pcl_if)
```

Quoting from the doc page linked to above:

> An interface library created with the above signature has no source files itself and is not included as a target in the generated buildsystem.

It does carry the interface properties of `pcl` and `flann`, however.